EXPDP doesn't recognise user names
I'm trying run EXPDP on an Oracle 19 database but it doesn't recognize any of the schema names apart from sys.
select * from dba_users; 

when run in Oracle SQL Developers returns all the users I'd expect to see but the same query run in sqlplus / as sysdba returns lots of entries like the attached image which seem to be missing any actual user details.
I'm new to database back ups and exports so I'm very likely missing something obvious but I haven't been able to figure it out.
expdp username/password schemas=user_1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=export_08_07_2024.dmp logfile=export_08_07_2024_export.log

ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'USER_1' does not correspond to any schemas.

I'm hoping to set this to run once a month and save the back ups but so far I haven't been able to get it to work.
--EDIT FOR MORE DETAILS--
select dbid, name, cdb from v$database; Gives the same output in sqlplus as in SQL Dev so they should be looking at the same database.
expdp system/passwd schemas=user_1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=export.dmp logfile=export.log
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'USER_1' does not correspond to any schemas.
I've tried running it as the system user since it doesn't recognise the account I'm actually trying to export.
Strangely I can get it to run using exp instead of expdp but it fails when it hits a table it doesn't like. So exp recognises the user/schema but expdp doesn't.

Is this issue with expdp or with your sqlplus output? If the latter, I think the reason you believe details are missing is simply a formatting side-effect. sqlplus honors the maximum width of each defined datatype and that creates massive wrapping effects due to its lack of a scrollbar. When combined with its outputting of column names as headers, you end up visually seeing almost only column headers and not data. The data is certainly there - it's just not easily viewable.

(continuation)... To fix, set column widths on very wide columns using the col .. format a30, etc. command, set a long line size set linesize ..., and only select the few columns you need, don't select *. You can usually get it down to where it's pretty readable and not wrapped. This does, however, illustrate how undesirable sqlplus is as an ad-hoc query tool. It's best used for executing scripts in files, batch jobs, etc.

Are you connecting to the same database? I would guess SQL Developer is connected to a PDB and SQL*Plus is connecting to the CDB, if it is seeing different data. And expdp could similarly be connecting to the wrong DB; or the user you are trying to export as doesn't have privileges to export the other schema. I can't remember off-hand what error that would produce, but does that user have the DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role?

You can try running select dbid, name, cdb from v$database in both SQL Developer and in SQL*Plus to see if they're the same database or not. They should match if they're the same.

select dbid, name, cdb from v$database; Gives the same output in sqlplus as in SQL Dev so they should be looking at the same database.
expdp system/passwd schemas=user_1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=export.dmp logfile=export.log
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39170: Schema expression 'USER_1' does not correspond to any schemas.
I've tried running it as the system user since it doesn't recognise the account I'm actually trying to export. Strangely I can get it to run using exp instead of expdp but it fails when it hits a table it doesn't like.

run the following cmd from cmd line.
expdp scott/****@db_name(PDB Name ex orclpdb) schemas=scott directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=scott_07232024.dmp logfile=scott_07232024.log
Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jul 23 16:27:44 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  scott/********@orclpdb schemas=scott directory=JAGAN_DIR dumpfile=scott_07232024.dmp logfile=scott_07232024.log
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
...SO ON until the end of script
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded

Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
C:\JAGAN\ORACLE_SCRIPTS\SCOTT_07232024.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Tue Jul 23 16:29:56 2024 elapsed 0 00:02:07

Thanks! This seems to be getting me closer to a solution. It is now rejecting the data_pump_dir directory as invalid which means it is at least accepting the user/schema name!
I'm guessing I need to create the DATA_PUMP_DIR directory somewhere that expdp can see it but not sure where the expdp would look for it as default.

yes DATA_PUMP_DIR need to be created.
Check with your DBA team to create the directory and grant permissions for your DATA_PUMP_DIR  dir to user schema.
